# $\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{k-n}dt=\frac{1}{n-k-1}$?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, special-functions

I am trying to find a series representation for $E_n(z)$, and I have gotten thus far: $$E_n(z)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-zt}}{t^n}dt$$
$$E_n(z)=\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{-n}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{(-z)^k}{k!}t^kdt$$
$$E_n(z)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{(-z)^k}{k!}\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{k-n}dt$$
$$E_n(z)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{(-z)^k}{k!}\biggl(\frac{t^{k-n+1}}{k-n+1}\biggr)\biggr|_{1}^{\infty}$$
$$E_n(z)=\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{(-z)^k}{k!}\biggl(\frac{1}{n-k-1}+\frac{1}{k-n+1}\lim_{t\to\infty}t^{k-n+1}\biggr)$$
I should know how to compute that limit, but I don't. [This site](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=x%5E%28k-n%29&lbound=1&ubound=inf&simplify=1) gives
$$\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{k-n}dt=\frac{1}{n-k-1}$$
for $n-k>0$, and $n-k-1>0$ which legitimately makes no sense. Did I do something wrong?

EDIT: I am not asking for a series representation for $E_n(z)$, as I am trying to find it myself, but I *am* trying to find out why the integral calculator I linked gave me the integral in the title, and if I could apply it to my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$
$\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}$
Let $n>1$ be an integer. Then

$$\e^s=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{s^k}{k!}+\frac{s^{n-1}}{(n-2)!}\int_0^1\e^{su}(1-u)^{n-2}\d u$$
so
$$\begin{align} E_n(z)&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\frac{(-z)^k}{k!(n-k+1)}+\frac{(-z)^{n-1}}{(n-2)!}\int_0^1 E_1(uz)(1-u)^{n-2}\d u& (\Re z &> 0)\end{align}\text{.}$$

The trouble is that $k=n-2$ is as far as the Maclaurin expansion can go: $$\begin{align} E_1(z)&\sim -\ln z& (z&\to 0)\text{.}\end{align}$$
But you can subtract out this logarithmic singularity to get
$$E_{n}\left(z\right)=\frac{(-z)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}(H_{n-1}-\ln z-\gamma)-\sum_{%
\begin{subarray}{c}k=0\\
k\neq n-1\end{subarray}}^{\infty}\frac{(-z)^{k}}{k!(1-n+k)}$$
([DLMF 8.19.8](https://dlmf.nist.gov/8.19#E8)) where 
$$H_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}$$
denotes the harmonic numbers and $\gamma$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.

Comment: could you explain the first formula, then show how you get the second formula?

Comment: The first formula is Taylor's theorem applied to $\mathrm{e}^{su}$ about $u=0$, evaluated at $u=1$. The second equation is the first, evaluated at $s=-tz$, multiplied by $t^{-n}$, and integrated with respect to $t$ from $t=1$ to $t=\infty$.

Comment: I appreciate the effort you have put into your answer, yet it does not help me. I see your derivation process, and I take your word for it that you can "subtract out the logarithmic singularity" (I don't know complex analysis). Yet I was asking if I had made any errors. I see that your result is similar to what I was thinking would be the answer, but I still do not know why the integral calculator gave me $$\int_{1}^{\infty}t^{k-n}dt=\frac{1}{n-k-1}$$

Comment: Your error is that you can't switch the infinite sum over $k$ and the improper integral over $t$, because the resulting series has well defined coefficients only for $k<n-1$ and divergent coefficients for $k$ otherwise (because $\lim_{t\to\infty}t^{k-n+1}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\ln t=\infty$). The failure of the Maclaurin expansion is to be expected because $E_n(z)$ is not $(n-1)$-times differentiable as $z\to 0$ and thus the hypotheses of Taylor's theorem do not hold.

Comment: perfect. Thank you.